# Updating a variable length html list via ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django

I would like to update a list in my template based on a response from an ajax call. As far as I understand it is not possible to send a list directly back from the view and iterate over it. That is why I tried to come up with an alternative, but I am kind of stuck. Here's my current code:

- Template (shortened):

  ```
  {% for a in attributes %}
    <li> a.name </li>
  {% endfor %}
  ```
- Ajax:

  ```
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'main:next_attributes' %}",
    data: {'next':'abc'},
    datatype : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    console.log("Success");}})
  ```

console.log should be replaced by something which iterates over new values and updates the values in the list above. Tricky part here is, that the number of list items might be different (both lower or higher) than before. However, I am unclear how the response from the view might look, which is why this still has a placeholder (see next part).

- Views.py:

  ```
  def next_attributes(request):
      keyword = request.GET.get('next', None)
      next_attributes = Attributes.objects.filter(keyword=keyword)    
      data = {'attributes':next_attributes}
      return JsonResponse(data)
  ```

Problem here is, that I cannot return a query result via JsonResponse..

In summary:
I want to get a new query result based on the filter given in the ajax request and update a list (variable length, based on query result) in my template. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You can use `Attributes.objects.filter(keyword=keyword).values('name')`, but remember that your template code runs on the server, not in the browser, so you'll have to use javascript to insert the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @thebjorn, you can use `Attributes.objects.filter(keyword=keyword).values('name')` to get the list of values. A full example would be the following:

```
def next_attributes(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get('next', None)
    next_attributes = Attributes.objects.filter(keyword=keyword).values('name')  
    data = {'attributes':next_attributes}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I am not entirely sure whether `.values` returns a JSON-serializable object, but the essence would be that.

Then, the expected object should look like this:

```
{'attributes': [{'name': 'name1'}, {'name': 'name2'}]}
```

Then, since you are using jQuery, you can do the following. Assuming your `<li>`'s are wrapped in a `<ul>` with id `myList`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'main:next_attributes' %}",
    data: {'next':'abc'},
    datatype : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#myList').empty(); // Clear old values
        data.attributes.forEach(function(element){
            $('#myList').append("<li>"+element.name+"</li>"); // Please note that this does not include any sanitization of the data. Be careful with that
        }
    }
}
```